# Grails: Integrating the Underlying Java(Spring+Hibernate) web app : sub-object not showing it s fields in form

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gsp, pojo

The problem is since my POJO/Domain classes are in java (obvious actually but just to make it clear) the sub-object that i use does'nt show up properly in the form when I click on available controllers: Eg: Patient has address -->> address is a sub-object in patient:
The address field shows a blank dropdown. How do i resolve this?
I am using def scaffold=  in the controller.

```
 package pojo;

public class Address {

private int id;
private String street;
private String city;
private String state;
private String country;
private Integer clinicid;
private Integer patientid;

public Address(){
super();
}


public int getId() {
return id;
}


public void setId(int id) {
this.id = id;
}


public String getStreet() {
return street;
}


public void setStreet(String street) {
this.street = street;
}


public String getCity() {
return city;
}


public void setCity(String city) {
this.city = city;
}


public String getState() {
return state;
}


public void setState(String state) {
this.state = state;
}


public String getCountry() {
return country;
}


public void setCountry(String country) {
this.country = country;
}

public Integer getClinicid() {
return clinicid;
}


public void setClinicid(Integer clinicid) {
this.clinicid = clinicid;
}


public Integer getPatientid() {
return patientid;
}


public void setPatientid(Integer patientid) {
this.patientid = patientid;
}

}


package pojo;


public class Clinic  {


private int  id ;     
private String clinicname ;
private Address address;
public int contactNumber;



public Clinic() {
address=new Address();
}

public int getId() {
return id;
}



public void setId(int id) {
this.id = id;
}



public String getClinicname() {
return clinicname;
}



public void setClinicname(String clinicname) {
this.clinicname = clinicname;
}



public Address getAddress() {
return address;
}



public void setAddress(Address address) {
address.setClinicid(this.id);
this.address = address;
}



public int getContactNumber() {
return contactNumber;
}



public void setContactNumber(int contactNumber) {
this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
} }




package pojo;

import java.util.*;

public class Doctor {

private int id      ;
private Date dateOfBirth  ;
private String username; 
private String password ; 
//private String name  ;
private int contactNumber ;
private String specialization ;
public Clinic clinic;


public Doctor(){
clinic=new Clinic();
}

public Clinic getClinic() {
return clinic;
}
public void setClinic(Clinic clinic) {
this.clinic = clinic;
}

/*public Doctor() {

}*/
public int getId() {
return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
this.id = id;
}
public Date getDateOfBirth() {
return dateOfBirth;
}
 public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
   this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}
public String getUsername() {
return username;
}
 public void setUsername(String username) {
this.username = username;
}
 public String getPassword() {
 return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
this.password = password;
}

public int getContactNumber() {
return contactNumber;
}
public void setContactNumber(int contactNumber) {
this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
}
public String getSpecialization() {
return specialization;
}
public void setSpecialization(String specialization) {
this.specialization = specialization;
}
}




package pojo;
import java.util.*;
public class Patient  {

private int id;
private Date dateOfBirth;
private Date registrationDate;
private String name ;
public int contactNumber; 
public  enum sexenum {MALE, FEMALE}
public sexenum sex;
private Address address;
private Clinic clinic;
private Doctor doctor;

public Patient(){
clinic=new Clinic();
doctor=new Doctor();
}

public int getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
this.id = id;
}
public Date getDateOfBirth() {
return dateOfBirth;
}
public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}
public Date getRegistrationDate() {
return registrationDate;
}
public void setRegistrationDate(Date registrationDate) {
 this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
 }

public String getName() {
return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
 this.name = name;
  }

 public int getContactNumber() {
 return contactNumber;
 }

  public void setContactNumber(int contactNumber) {
  this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
  }

 public sexenum getSex() {
 return sex;
 }

 public void setSex(sexenum sex) {
 this.sex = sex;
  }

 public Address getAddress() {
 return address;
 }

 public void setAddress(Address address) {
 address.setPatientid(this.id);
 this.address = address;
 }

 public Clinic getClinic() {
 return clinic;
}

 public void setClinic(Clinic clinic) {
 this.clinic = clinic;
  }

 public Doctor getDoctor() {
  return doctor;
   }

  public void setDoctor(Doctor doctor) {
  this.doctor = doctor;
   }


    } 

 patient [ one to one with ] address;.
clinic [ one to one with ] address;.
doctorid [ foreign key  many to one]where ever referenced.
clinic id [foreign key many to one ] where ever referenced.
```

Comment: @cdeszaq Here it is.! Thank you.!

Comment: It would be helpful to include the code for your domain objects so we can see how they are set up (with relationships, etc.)

Comment: @David Sure i ll edit the question.

Comment: Ah. So these aren't real Grails domain objects, they're coming from a different source. Hmm. I'm not sure how well scaffolding will work in this case. I think you would probably need proper domain objects with the hasMany{} and belongsTo{} closures set appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Grails only supports GORM-mappings (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#ormdsl) and hibernate mappings (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#hibernate)

I don't think the mappings you provide are valid for scaffolding.